# PyInstaller doesn't access files that i bundled while compiling

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

This may seem like a dumb question, but the code i compiled tries to access files from the directory the exe is in, but the exe has the same path and required files within. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html)

```
from os import path
import sys
bundle_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))
path_to_file = path.join(bundle_dir, 'file')
```